# react-native watchman error, after npm start on Ubuntu 17.10.

Tags: dependencies, npm

I am trying to start project of React-native on Ubuntu, node,npm are at latest versions.
according to documentation I have Install all official `create-react-native-app` and its dependencies.

here is my output screen after npm start

```
gd@gd:~/Desktop$ cd testing7/
gd@gd:~/Desktop/testing7$ npm start

> testing7@0.1.0 start /home/gd/Desktop/testing7
> react-native-scripts start

10:01:07: Starting packager...
***ERROR STARTING PACKAGER***
Starting React Native packager...
Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/gd/Desktop/testing7/node_modules (44ms)
Loading dependency graph.



jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1523075484: opendir(/home/gd/Desktop/testing7/node_modules/metro/node_modules/ansi-regex) -> The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached; increase the fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-opendir. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run following commands or make bash files with following contents and

run as `bash yourfilename.sh`

```
touch .watchmanconfig
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
sudo pkill -9 -x fseventsd
echo fs.inotify.max_user_instances=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
echo fs.inotify.max_queued_events=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: can you explain what it does?

Answer (score 5):

Try these two commands

```
`watchman watch-del-all`
`watchman shutdown-server`
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this command:**

```
echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
watchman shutdown-server
```

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting WatchMan errors check out this page [here](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch)